# Rainbow Jquery Plugin does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to implement the rainbow jquery plugin on my blog: https://levalencia-public.sharepoint.com/blog

Rainbow plugin here:
http://craig.is/making/rainbows

I have included the following on the head

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/rainbow/kimbie-dark.css" />
```

I have included the following before the body end tag

```
 <!-- you can create a custom build with specific languages this should go before the closing </body> -->
        <script src="js/rainbow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/languages/generic.js"></script>
        <script src="js/languages/csharp.js"></script>
        <script src="js/languages/css.js"></script>
        <script src="js/languages/html.js"></script>
        <script src="js/languages/javascript.js"></script>
        <script src="js/languages/shell.js"></script>

         <script> //<![CDATA[
              $(document).ready(function() {
                Rainbow.color();
              });
              //]]>
        </script>
```

Then I included one post to test it with the code:

```
<pre><code data-language="javascript">var testing = true;</code></pre>
```

When I check the source code of my blog, it looks like the html is being changed, because I see this:

[image]

If I debug the rainbow.color is being hit.
So I am clueless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Rainbow initializes itself so you should be able to remove this without any problem:

```
<script> //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Rainbow.color();
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

The main issue you are seeing is that your theme file is not being included correctly.  If you look at the theme you are including it is not a valid css file.  It is returning some sort of html.

See
https://levalencia-public.sharepoint.com/_catalogs/masterpage/css/rainbow/kimbie-dark.css

Comment: thanks Craig, I guess I renamed a file by mistake and uploaded it there! now it works!